# setExceptionListener when using @JmsListener

Tags: spring-jms

I would like to catch an exception if the receiving queue is broken, and I know there is a function setExceptionListener on a connection. I do not understand how this function can be set when using @JmsListener and DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory. Can someone point me in the right direction. I also tried to use JmsListenerEndpointRegistry, however I cannot get access to the connection to setExceptionListener. I have used 
@JmsListener(destination = "${mq.incoming-queueProducts}", containerFactory = "DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory")

```
@Bean(name = "DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory")
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory provideJmsListenerContainerFactory(
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setRecoveryInterval(10000L);        
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory());

    return factory;
}

@Bean(name = "JmsTemplate")
public JmsTemplate provideJmsTemplate() {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory());
    return jmsTemplate;
}

private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    ConnectionFactory factory = null;
    try {
        factory = new MQConnectionFactory();
        ((MQConnectionFactory) factory).setHostName(properties.getHost());
        ((MQConnectionFactory) factory).setPort(properties.getPort());
        ((MQConnectionFactory) factory).setQueueManager(properties.getQueueManager());
        ((MQConnectionFactory) factory).setChannel(properties.getChannel());
        ((MQConnectionFactory) factory).setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);

    } catch (JMSException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return factory;
}

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mq")
public static class MQProperties {
    String queueManager;
    String host;
    int port;
    String channel;
    String incomingQueueProducts;
    String incomingQueueStores;
    String incomingQueueShipments;

    public String getQueueManager() {
        return queueManager;
    }

    public void setQueueManager(String queueManager) {
        this.queueManager = queueManager;
    }

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public String getChannel() {
        return channel;
    }

    public void setChannel(String channel) {
        this.channel = channel;
    }

    public String getIncomingQueueProducts() {
        return incomingQueueProducts;
    }

    public void setIncomingQueueProducts(String incomingQueueProducts) {
        this.incomingQueueProducts = incomingQueueProducts;
    }

    public String getIncomingQueueStores() {
        return incomingQueueStores;
    }

    public void setIncomingQueueStores(String incomingQueueStores) {
        this.incomingQueueStores = incomingQueueStores;
    }

    public String getIncomingQueueShipments() {
        return incomingQueueShipments;
    }

    public void setIncomingQueueShipments(String incomingQueueShipments) {
        this.incomingQueueShipments = incomingQueueShipments;
    }

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "queue is broken". The `ExceptionListener` is set on the connection factory and only relates to `Connection` objects; it has nothing to do with queues.

Comment: If the message broker goes away, I would like to throw an application specific message and update the status of the queue to offline. When the broker come back, I would like to update the status of the queue to online. That is ultimately what I am trying to accomplish. Thank you.

Comment: The exception listener is configured on the connection factory.

Comment: @GaryRussell what do you mean when you say "the exception listener is configured on the connection factory"? Is this configurable when creating an instance of DMLC?

Comment: Please don't ask new questions on old answers; ask a new question instead. As I said above, `ExceptionListener` is related to connections, and is configured on the connection factory, it has nothing to do with listener containers. Ask a new question if there is something more specific that you need an answer for.